# Text Display Different

Tags: css, windows, macos, google-chrome

I am having an issue with a section of text looking "bolder" on Windows then it does on Mac.

How do I get it displaying the same?

Both browsers are Chrome and its only happening in Chrome.

**CSS:**

```
#featured-slider .slide-content header h1 a, #featured-slider .slide-content footer h1 a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 20px;
font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

**Mac:**

[image]

**Windows:**
[image]

Comment: You should explicitly set the font-weight for Open Sans. http://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/

Comment: Insufficient information: HTML markup missing, `@font-face` rule missing, information about font origin missing (presumably Google web font, but processed how?). Screen shots are probably differently zoomed. Guess: `font-weight: bold` is in effect but the font is not declared as bold, and some browsers may thus apply algorithmic bolding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use short hand properties like this:

```
font: normal 20px 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif !important;
```

Comment: The use of normal here will override the default boldness of the h1 element. Not sure that's what asker wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the css set up, it will default to a different font if the first choice is not available. I can't tell if it is doing this from the picture.

It might also be a change in the "font-weight" property.

See if adding this fixes it:

```
font-weight:normal;
```

or:

```
font-weight:400;
```